# Not able to see the data in App insight of azure portal

Tags: azure-application-insights, azureportal, visual-studio-app-center

I had created app for iOS and android in Appcenter.ms.

1) Integrated the SDK
2) Added the event.
3) I can see the events and log flow in the appcenter.ms
But not in the Application insights on Portal.azure.com.

As show in this i did followed the steps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/export

Adding an Azure Subscription

App belonging to an organization: If you are the organization admin, go to the Manage section under the organization where the app belongs to.
App belonging to a user: If you are the app owner, follow these steps.
Login to Appcenter portal
Go to user settings.
Under Azure, click Add subscription
Select an existing Azure subscription or create a new one.

Also this :

On the Appcenter Portal, choose the App.
Go to the App Settings.
Click on Export and select the New Export option.
Select blog storage or Application Insights based on your app needs.
Select the type of configuration . I had click the customization and added the instrumentation key for the application.

Comment: It sounds like you did everything right. It takes a few minutes to initialize thought, how long has it been at this point?

Comment: its been 15 min but i am not able to get any data in azure portal

Comment: In Portal.azure.com i can see the application insights but inside that i can not see the two application for iOS and android.

Comment: When i did it, it worked within 10 minutes. I would reach out to the help on MS App Center. They are pretty good, though they can be slow at responding sometimes